# Facebook user Graph does not return Email PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the whole Facebook API.
I am creating a login page for users, and the idea is that they login with Facebook.

At the top of login page I have the following code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => "$fb_appid",
    'app_secret' => "$fb_appsecret",
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
```

Then a little lower I have the login button:

```
if(isset($fb)){
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email']; // optional
    $fb_login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl("$server_url/public/facebook/login-callback", $permissions);
} else $fb_login_url = "";

if(strlen($fb_login_url) >= 1) echo "<a href='$fb_login_url'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-facebook-square'></i></a>";
else echo "<a href='#' disabled='disabled'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-facebook-square'></i></a>";
```

The code works up until there, if I click the button, I go through to the Facebook portal, click the allow for the permissions and whatever, then it redirects me to `login-callback`.

The code on `login-callback` is:

```
if(isset($fb)){
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        $err_message = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        access_log("facebook_login","IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        $err_message = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        access_log("facebook_login","IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
    }

    if (strlen($err_message) <= 0 && isset($accessToken)) {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken("$accessToken");

        try {
            $response = $fb->get('/me');
            $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();

//            $username = $userNode->getName();
//            $firstname = $userNode->getFirstName();
//            $lastname = $userNode->getLastName();
            print_r($userNode);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            $err_message =  'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            access_log("facebook_login","IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            $err_message =  'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            access_log("facebook_login","IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
        }
    }
}
```

The `$userNode` looks like this:

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jacques Koekemoer
            [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )

)
```

I have set the permissions to allow for the email, and if I am not mistaken the public profile is sent automatically.

I have also checked that the button on the login page does have "&scope=email". Below is the code that I have right on the page right now in the login button:

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxx&state=xxxxxxxx&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.za%2Fpublic%2Ffacebook%2Flogin-callback&scope=email`

I replaced the `client_id`, `state` and domain name because I don't want that information available publicly as I don't know what people can do with it.

Let me know if it is needed to solve the problem.

I used the Facebook guide [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4) to setup and download the SDK.

Comment: You need to specify that you want the email field

Comment: @WizKid Is that not why I have the `$permissions = ['email']; // optional` when I create the login URL? I thought that when it ads the `scope=email` bit at the end of the URL that requests the email? Or do you mean in the `login-callback` file?

Comment: No scope emails ask for the email permission. You also need to specify that you want the field later.

Comment: @WizKid could you perhaps tell me where to specify the email field?

Comment: Go read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: @CBroe didn't help much. I read through the entire api changes and nothing pointed in the right direction, this isn't because you provided the wrong link or anything, its because facebook's api is incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

You need to request specific fields from Facebook in the `get` function.

`$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');`

This can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/5.0.0).

A full list of fields that you can query can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

**Example**

```
if (isset($fb)) {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        $err_message = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        access_log("facebook_login", "IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        $err_message = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        access_log("facebook_login", "IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
    }

    if (strlen($err_message) <= 0 && isset($accessToken)) {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken("$accessToken");

        try {
           // this here is where you specify the fields
            $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');
            $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
            /* handle the result */
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            $err_message = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            access_log("facebook_login", "IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            $err_message = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            access_log("facebook_login", "IP:$client_ip\r\nFacebook Error: $err_message");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: … and that is exactly what the “Declarative Fields” section in the changelog that I linked to is about.

Comment: @CBroe okay I see now, I don't know how I missed that the first time around. :) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

One of the my friend was trying to the issue from last 5 days. huummm very irritating. which got love in 2 min...

Assumption: using PHP for O2Authentication
Solution:

```
$loginURL =  $fb->getLoginUrl({your redirect URL},['email']);
```

And job is done.

Thanks & Regards

Jaiswar Vipin Kumar R.

Answer (score -1):

Check you app version if it is version 2.2 or lower, it will work fine , it is not than it will not return. for that you have to request api with scope for email access.

Comment: Where do I check that? In my facebook developer console? Because I used the guide on their website to download the SDK etc..
The guide is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4

And It is version 2.4 in my panel as well.