# Facebook SDK 3.2.2 get fields from Api 2.4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a website with facebook sdk 3.2.2 and php 5.3x running. now i made a new facebook app with api 2.4 and no data like name and email is returned anymore. Is there any way to change the php code in the sdk to get the new fields ? i cannot upgrade to php 5.4 so i need a fix to get the necessary fields.

would be nice if anybody can help me !

my website is with codeigniter but i don´t know at the moment where to change the api

maybe here ? it´s very hard to find any good help.

```
$this->api = new Facebook( ARRAY( 'appId' => $this->config["keys"]["id"],'secret' => $this->config["keys"]["secret"]) );
```

Comment: If you are able to upgrade your PHP, I had the exact same question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858341/facebook-user-graph-does-not-return-email-php

Have a look at it, maybe it will solve your problem as well. You can find a list of user fields here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Comment: You don’t need to change the SDK code itself, but only your API calls.

Comment: Hi Jacques thanx but this answer does not help me :) Cbroe could you tell me which api call i have to change ? i´m very new to php facebook sdk . my website is with codeignitter and at the moment i do not know where to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes it is better to stop and think about it. I have found a solution to get it to work . In my fbauth_core.php file i have changed the following :

```
// Get user's data and print it
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');

        $this->load->model('auth_model');
```

to

```
// Get user's data and print it
            // $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,gender');
        $this->load->model('auth_model');
```

and now it is working fine again :) But thanx again !!!